# Where is the default directory where the windows service creates a file?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-services

I have created a windows service which appends a string to a file.
So, for the first time it creates a file and then keeps appending a string to it every 10 seconds.

So, my question is where is the default directory for a windows service to create files, **if not specified**. It does not seem to be the service's executable directory as I do not see any file being created there. Google has stopped being my buddy here.

Any help would be invaluable.

Thanks.

Comment: If the file has a unique name you could always search for it. But generally speaking, if you want to write to a file from a service, you should really set up a working directory explicitly.

Comment: Tried searching and failed. I thought if not the executable directory then it should be in the system folders. But, yeah still not found.

Comment: Do you check if your file is being opened and if write is happening at all?

Comment: Based on what information do you assume, that there would be a default directory? Have you discarded the possibility, that files are created in the directory returned from [GetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934.aspx)?

Comment: @Drop Attached the service process to the visual studio debugger. And the file handle gets created successfully for me to append data to it.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes. Based on my comment above, "currentdirectory" is not where the file is getting created.

Comment: Is `currentdirectory` a system or write-protected folder? In this case it can appear in `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special about a service in this regard. If you specify a relative path then it is relative to the process current directory, also known as the working directory. This is documented: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces, Fully Qualified vs. Relative Paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths).

So, the answer to your question is that your file is saved in the process current directory, whatever that happens to be. A consequence of using relative paths in this way is that you are at the mercy of the process current directory. That is something that is not always predictable. So, best practise is not to use a relative path for such a task. Be explicit. Decide where you want the file to be stored, and use a fully-qualified absolute path.

Comment: Makes it more clear. Thanks! If you think the question makes sense please upvote!

Comment: Please don't ask for upvotes. That's not really how we operate here. Thank you.

Comment: @SRINI794: Your question really doesn't make much sense. It follows the *"what, if I decide to neglect best practices?"* pattern. The solution to this is: Do not neglect best practices. Specifically, use fully qualified path names. A question asking for help with problems that stem from poor decisions is usually not very helpful to others.